# java lyx to String

Tags: java, lyx

I would like to know if there are any java libaries which can extract the plain text of a .lyx document, so that I get the unformated content for further analysis. This seems like a relatively easy job, but I so long, I didn't find anything which I could integrate in my project.

Daniel

Comment: couldn't you simply use BufferedReader and read only the lines that don't start with "\" or "%", or "#" (looks like those prefix annotations)

Comment: Would it be an option to use LyX to export the .lyx file to plain text? This could be done on the command line with `lyx -e text yourfile.lyx`

Comment: @Birgit Martinelle: I guess that would be an option, I just thought  that there would already be a parser, so that I don't have to learn about those prefexis myselve.

Comment: @scottkosty: Thanks for the hint, maybe I'll find a way to do it this way.